# Ruby multithreading

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex

I have code that is running in a manner similar to the sample code below. There are two threads that loop at certain time intervals. The first thread sets a flag and depending on the value of this flag the second thread prints out a result. My question is in a situation like this where only one thread is changing the value of the resource (@flag), and the second thread is only accessing its value but not changing it, is a mutex lock required? Any explanations?

```
Class Sample

  def initialize
    @flag=""
    @wait_interval1 = 20
    @wait_interval2 = 5
  end

  def thread1(x)
    Thread.start do
    loop do
      if x.is_a?(String)
        @flag = 0
      else
        @flag = 1
      sleep @wait_interval
    end
    end
  end

  def thread2(y)
    Thread.start do
    loop do
      if @flag == 0
        if y.start_with?("a")
          puts "yes"
        else
          puts "no"
        end
      end
    end
   end
   end

end
```

Comment: Why does `@flag` start out as an empty string, and then later become one of `1` or `0`? Wouldn't `nil` be a better starting value? Testing that the thing is a string is a very, very odd way of doing this. You'd be better with `x.nil?`

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, the mutex lock is required (or better yet, a read/write lock so multiple reads can run in parallel and the exclusive lock's only needed when changing the value).

It's possible to avoid needing the lock if you can guarantee that the underlying accesses (both the read and the write) are atomic (they happen as one uninterruptible action so it's not possible for two to overlap). On modern multi-core and multi-processor hardware it's difficult to guarantee that, and when you add in virtualization and semi-interpreted languages like Ruby it's all but impossible. Don't be fooled into thinking that being 99.999% certain there won't be an overlap is enough, that just means you can expect an error due to lack of locking once every 100,000 iterations which translates to several times a second for your code and probably at least once every couple of seconds for the kind of code you'd see in a real application. That's why it's advisable to follow the general rule and not worry about when it's safe to break it until you've exhausted every other option for getting acceptable performance and shown through profiling that it's acquiring/releasing that lock that's the bottleneck.